# Grails GORM best practices

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Does anyone know if there is a definitive best practices guide for GORM? I find information scattered across different blogs and different resources, but I can't find a definitive guide.  I find stuff that says to not do database related stuff in controllers and to keep those things in the service layer, for example. However, it'd just be nice to se what the suggested approach for writing a simple web app is. Should we always use command objects in controllers and pass those command objects to services? Should we store those command objects in session rather than storing actual domain objects in session, which seems to cause a lot of lazy init exceptions, etc.?

I've tried to piece together the information that I've found, but if anyone knows of a comprehensive resource, that would be great.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is some great information available from the GORM Gotchas series. It's in three parts.

[GORM Gotchas (Part 1)](http://spring.io/blog/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/)

[GORM Gotchas (Part 2)](http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/)

[GORM Gotchas (Part 3)](http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/28/gorm-gotchas-part-3/)

To answer your specific questions about Services and Command objects.

Q: "Should we always use command objects and Services?"

A: Some would argue that it's overkill to do so, however I personally think it's a great pattern and makes things much easier to test and extend. It may seem like a lot of effort but it does pay off in large projects.

Q: "Should we store command objects in session rather than domain objects?"

A: Store as little in the session as possible (if at all). If you have to store something there it's best that it be small and light weight. Command objects (typically) are going to be better for this than a Domain class.

**Update (11/19/2014)**

I'd like to highlight a very good series that outlines a lot of the potential issues faced using GORM and Hibernate. It's very long, but worth reading if you plan on using GORM/Hibernate in a large scale multi-user project. Don't be turned away by the negative approach because it **does** contain a lot of useful information.

[I don't like Hibernate (and Grails), PART 1](http://rpeszek.blogspot.com/2014/08/i-dont-like-hibernate-and-grails-part-1.html)

[I don't like Hibernate/Grails, part 2, repeatable finder problem: trust in nothing!](http://rpeszek.blogspot.com/2014/08/i-dont-like-hibernategrails-part-2.html)

[I don't like Grails/Hibernate part 3. DuplicateKeyException: Catch it if you can.](http://rpeszek.blogspot.com/2014/08/i-dont-like-grailshibernate-part-3.html)

[I don't like Grails/Hibernate, part 4. Hibernate proxy objects.](http://rpeszek.blogspot.com/2014/08/i-dont-like-grailshibernat-part-4.html)

[I don't like Hibernate/Grails part 5: auto-saving and auto-flushing](http://rpeszek.blogspot.com/2014/08/i-dont-like-hibernategrails-part-5-auto.html)

[I don't like Hibernate/Grails part 6, how to save objects using refresh()](http://rpeszek.blogspot.com/2014/09/i-dont-like-hibernategrails-part-6-how.html)

[I don't like Hibernate/Grails part 7: working on more complex project](http://rpeszek.blogspot.com/2014/09/i-dont-like-hibernategrails-part-7.html)

[I don't like Hibernate/Grails, part 8, but some like Hibernate and Grails. Why?](http://rpeszek.blogspot.com/2014/10/i-dont-like-hibernategrails-part-8-but.html)

[I don't like Hibernate/Grails part 9: Testable code](http://rpeszek.blogspot.com/2014/10/i-dont-like-hibernategrails-part-9.html)

[I don't like Hibernate/Grails part 10: Repeatable finder, lessons learned](http://rpeszek.blogspot.com/2014/10/i-dont-like-hibernategrails-part-10.html)

[I don't like Hibernate/Grails part 11. Final thoughts.](http://rpeszek.blogspot.com/2014/10/i-dont-like-hibernategrails-part-11_31.html)

Comment: Good answer. :) Best part I like in using command object (or any other object using @Validateable) is `constraints`. This makes sure all validation errors (or additionally business exceptions) is handled way before moving to service class to handle business logic. Good level of abstraction is achieved if we do so.

Comment: Agreed. Not only that they can be used for more than data collected via controllers. JMS messages, Spring Integration channels, Spring batch jobs, etc. Very flexible yet provide you with a nice "contract" with your services.

Comment: Great, thanks! I've seen some of the GORM Gotchas stuff before and it was definitely helpful. You confirmed my thoughts though that storing lots of domain objects in session is bad and we should be using more light weight stuff.

Answer (score 4):

The book [Grails in Action](http://www.manning.com/gsmith2/) talks a lot about best practices in Grails. At the time of this writing it isn't published in its final form, but you can buy and read the preview.

I was recently looking for the same answers you are asking and that book has helped me a lot.

Comment: The book is pretty close to completion, too. An update was just released in the last week or two where every chapter was updated. The authors have stated that they just have some minor clean up and then it will be finished.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I will definitely check that book out.